# Calculating $cov(\hat{Y}, e)$ in Multiple Linear Regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

For the multiple linear regression, I have

$Y_{n\times 1} = X_{n\times k}\beta_{k\times 1} + \epsilon_{n\times 1}$ and $\hat{Y} = X\hat{B} $ where $\hat{B} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$

$\hat{Y} = X\hat{\beta} = X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y = HY$ where $H = X(X'X)^{-1}X' $ is symmetric, idempotent matrix

Similarly, $e = Y - \hat{Y} = Y - Hy = (I_n - H)Y = \overline{H} Y$ where $\overline{H} = I_n - H$ is again symmetric, idempotent matrix.

I am interested in calculating

$cov(\hat{Y}, e) = cov(HY, \overline{H}Y)$

How can I calculate this? Basically, how do I open this up so that I am able to use nice properties of $H$ and $\overline{H}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $X$ is a known matrix. We're looking for the cross-covariance matrix:
$$\begin{align}cov(\hat Y,e)&=E[HYY^T\bar H^T]-E[HY]E[Y^T\bar H^T]\\&=H E[YY^T]\bar H-HE[Y]E[Y^T]\bar H\\&=H cov(Y)\bar H\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can argue using properties of projections: $\hat Y=HY$ is a projection into a subspace $\mathbb{D}$ and $e=(I-H)Y$ is the projection into its orthogonal complement $\mathbb{D}^\perp$.  Since any vector in $\mathbb{D}$ is orthogonal to any vector in $\mathbb{D}^\perp$, the covariance is identically zero.